# Crawled pages but scrape 0 items; contents through scrapy shell fetch different from that in HTML in dev tool

Tags: python, json

I'm a newbie in scrapy frame. I would like to scrape the news from https://www.snl24.com/dailysun/news. It will pop up news through infinite scroll. I encontered 2 issues during these days.

1. Since it needs infinite scroll to refresh new contents, so I find the url is `https://www.snl24.com/dailysun/news?pagenumber={page_number}`` in the dev tool. Ended with the specific page number. And it can also be found from the html of the former page.

   [image]

```
        <div id="loader-4" class="loader-indicator"> </div>
        <div hx-get="dailysun/news?pagenumber=5" hx-trigger="revealed" hx-swap="afterend" hx-indicator="#loader-4">
             </div>
        <script type="module">
            import loadmore from './js/modules/loadmore.min.js?v=3.0.23346.2+7f752273116078cde5037260c2a234b39f3ca4de';
            new loadmore();
        </script>
```

The contents in html from the dev tool looks fine and consist with what shows on the web, but the content fetched ended with `?pagenumber=4` (for example) is totally confusing and different from what in dev tool.

2. If I run the code below, it shows I crawl the page successfully but scraped no items. The output file contains only little part of the data. And it keeps crawling but output no data anymore.

   [image]

```
2023-12-23 00:41:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.snl24.com/dailysun/News?pagenumber=72> (referer: https://www.snl24.com/dailysun/News?pagenumber=71)
2023-12-23 00:42:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.snl24.com/dailysun/News?pagenumber=73> (referer: https://www.snl24.com/dailysun/News?pagenumber=72)
2023-12-23 00:42:02 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 95 pages (at 37 pages/min), scraped 21 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-12-23 00:42:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.snl24.com/dailysun/News?pagenumber=74> (referer: https://www.snl24.com/dailysun/News?pagenumber=73)
2023-12-23 00:42:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.snl24.com/dailysun/News?pagenumber=75> (referer: https://www.snl24.com/dailysun/News?pagenumber=74)
```

```
import scrapy, time
from scrapy_lyntest.items import ScrapyLyntestItem

class DailysunSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "DailySun"
    allowed_domains = ["www.snl24.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.snl24.com/dailysun/news']

    def parse(self, response):
        newss = response.css('div.article-item--container')
        for news in newss:
            inner_news_relative_url = news.css('a[data-event-name="article_link"]::attr(href)').get()
            inner_news_url = 'https://www.snl24.com' + inner_news_relative_url
            yield response.follow(inner_news_url, callback = self.parse_news_page)

        if response.css('div.loader-indicator').attrib['class'] == 'loader-indicator':
            scroll_relative_url = response.css('div[hx-trigger="revealed"]::attr(hx-get)').get()
            scroll_url = 'https://www.snl24.com/' + scroll_relative_url
            yield scrapy.Request(url = scroll_url, callback=self.parse)
            
            
    def parse_news_page(self, response):
        newspage = response.css('div.article.tf-lhs-col')
        news_item = ScrapyLyntestItem()

        news_item["url"] = response.url,
        news_item["title"] = newspage.css('h1.article__title::text').get(),
        news_item["content"] = newspage.css('div.article__body.NewsArticle p::text').getall(),
        news_item["date"] = newspage.css('p.article__date::text').get()
        
        yield news_item
```

I tried to `json.loads(response.text)` what I get through fetching the url ended with pagenumber={}. But it pops up the error message `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)` so I tried to use css directly.

Need help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, not an images

Comment: @toyotaSupra The texts on the images are added now.